# Slow .Net Core restore/run/watch while in Docker Container

Tags: .net, docker, .net-core, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to containerize my applications and to deploy them temporarily with docker-compose on Azure. Locally, I am trying to develop my applications using docker-compose by letting it build off of my Dockerfiles in each project. Those Dockerfiles are configured to run a development environment, mounting my workspace and `dotnet watch`ing each project. Problem is that any dotnet core project that I run in this configuration, it takes minutes to start the watch service and to actually start the app. I am losing a lot of time waiting so I am calling here for help. I followed this [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/csharp/comments/9cyl6a/debugging_dotnet_watch_processes_inside_of_a/) to get this configuration working in the first place. My folder structure looks like:

```
-xxx.Web
L_ Dockerfile
-xxx.Landing
L_ Dockerfile
-xxx.Metrics
L_ Dockerfile
-docker-compose.yaml
```

My Dockerfile for project xxx.Landing (which was a brand new project with ReactJS I was working on and it was STILL as slow as my older projects):

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1

WORKDIR /vsdbg

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
            unzip \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && curl -sSL https://aka.ms/getvsdbgsh \
        | bash /dev/stdin -v latest -l /vsdbg

# ENV DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER 1
# ENV DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT 1

WORKDIR /app
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x |  bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs

ENTRYPOINT dotnet watch run --urls=http://*:80
```

And the relevant part of the docker-compose.yml:

```
...
    landing:
      container_name: xxxlanding
      build: 
        context: ./xxx.Landing
      volumes:
        - ./xxx.Landing:/app
      # working_dir: /app
      # command: dotnet watch run --urls http://*:80
      environment:
        - DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER=1
        - DOTNET_ROLL_FORWARD_ON_NO_CANDIDATE_FX=2
        - DOTNET_CLI_HOME=/sdk
        - DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT=1
        - xxx_DEVELOPMENT=1
      ports:
          - "80:80"
      restart: always
      depends_on:
          - cache
          - web
...
```

And like I said earlier, I don't think it is relevant to post any code from my project since it seems not to matter at all which project is being containerized. Any help, tips, or thoughts is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are you using to run docker (WSL/Windows/OSX/Linux)?

Comment: @octagon_octopus Sorry, should have included this, but I am running Linux containers in a MacOS environment.

Comment: Not sure if the OS is an issue then. I don't have experience with running docker in MacOS. You could try using a `COPY` instruction to copy `xxx.Landing` into your image through the Dockerfile instead of mounting it as a volume in your `docker-compose.yml`. It could be an I/O issue with the volume, because it has to read and write to the MacOS file system.

Comment: @octagon_octopus Sorry, I kinda forgot about this post, what I did do was I ended up switching to a dedicated development host on a unix machine and connecting to it using VS Codespaces and it works like a charm. I'm concluding that maybe MacOS wasn't doing too well with file pollers or something IO related.